# Sparkfun's Uberboard HELP

Tags: arm7, sparkfun

I bought the Sparkfun's [Uberboard](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/555) a while back and I was trying to run the ["Bootloader Tutorial"](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/94) I followed all the instructions, got the FW.SFE file, but when the Uberboard resets it does not load the code. I got the following:

> SparkFun USB Bootloader v1.1 Boot up
>   complete No USB Detected Failed
>   Reading Header opening filesystem
>   failed Root open "UART0 setup...ing
>   firmware...

The "Failed reading header" what does it means? help, anyone? :S

Comment: There are some comments on the bootloader on the Sparkfun page. Also, have you tried the Sparkfun forum?

Comment: Done that, my friend. And no answers whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

From the sparkfun website:

HOW TO USE THE BOOTLOADER INCLUDED ON YOUR BOARD ---

Make sure you add the following to the Makefile: change build: elf hex lss sym to build: elf hex lss sym FW.SFE

--- insert this --- FW.SFE: main.elf @echo @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@ $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

--- after this block ---
Create final output file (.bin) from ELF output file.

%.bin: %.elf @echo @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@ $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) $< $@

and in the common folder change the following text in the file: LPC2138-ROM.ld change ROM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 512k to ROM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 380k

Otherwise it will won't write the file. Since the bootloader is sitting at 0x00000000.

I burned a few hours and brain cells on these issues. So, I hope it helps you!